# AspectGetter to get object from list

Tags: c#, listview, objectlistview

I have a list of items that I would like to bind to my ObjectListView and I think AspectGetter needs to be used to achieve this. How would I go about doing this?

I have tried this to generate additional columns but I am still unable to bind the data to show list items

```
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var disk in vmObject.DisksList)
        {
            // create column with vhd+count 
            OLVColumn diskColumn = new OLVColumn("Attached VHD " + count, disk.Path);

            // this lets you handle the model object directly
            diskColumn.AspectGetter = delegate(object rowObject)
            {
                // check if that is the expected model type
                if (rowObject is Model.HyperVTools.VMInfo)
                {
                    // return the value of disklist
                    return ((Model.HyperVTools.VMInfo)rowObject).DisksList;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            };

            columnsList.Add(diskColumn);
            count++;
        }


objectListView2.Columns.AddRange(columnsList.Cast<System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader>().ToArray());

        objectListView2.AddObject(vmObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop is unnecessary. You only need to create a column once. The same goes for the `AspectGetter`.

As soon as you add objects to the OLV, it will call the `AspectGetter` delegates to get the values automatically and create the corresponding rows. I suggest you take another look at the tutorial / examples.

Comment: I'm looking through the tutorial again and am still confused on how I would use it in my code. The reason I do the foreach loop is to create the additional columns for the VHDs in hopes that I can show just that particular VHD info per column.

Comment: I am not sure what you try to accomplish. Are you mixing up columns and rows? It would maybe make some sense if you would include the "count" an each `row` but I don't see why you would want to initialize the `column` header that way and add multiple columns like you do it now.

Comment: VM info will be displayed on a per row basis, each VM will have X count of attached VHDs. I store these VHDs in a List<DiskList>, I am trying to display this information in a new column but am not sure how to generate the appropriate column with the appropriate AspectName. Hope that makes sense